# Column 'book_name' does not belong to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to add data into two fields in my VB form from SQL server with these column values `book_name` & `member_id` through two `textboxes` and a `search button` using the following code:

```
Dim B_Name As String = txtSearchBookNamenew.Text
Dim M_ID As Decimal = txtSearchIDnew.Text
da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT b.book_name, m.member_id FROM book b JOIN member m ON b.staff_id = m.staff_id Where member_id =" & M_ID & "AND book_name =" & "'" & B_Name & "'", cn)
                dt = New DataTable
                da.Fill(dt)
                If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                    cboIDSave.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("member_id")
                    cboISBNsave.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("book_name")
                    end if
```

But I am receiving this Error: `"Column 'book_name' does not belong to table"`

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Use SQL parameters.  If the book name is "The Hobbit's Quest"  your query will crash.  They will also make the code/query  easier to read.  Also turn on Option Strict

Comment: just in case you didn't came to it, looks like the column "book_name" doesn't exits in the table "book". At least in the server you're connected to. Maybe is a typo and your column is "name" or "bookName"

Comment: @Plutonix how to turn on option strict ?

Comment: `Option Strict On` at the top of the file/class, better to make it a Project and even VS default ( Tools menu -> Options -> Projects - -> VB -> Option Strict On )

Comment: @Plutonix  I turned on the `option strict` from settings and also I brought below changes to my code: `da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT b.book_name book_name, m.member_id FROM book b JOIN member m ON b.staff_id = m.staff_id Where member_id =@member_id AND book_name =@book_name", cn)`
            `da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@book_name", B_Name)`
             `da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@member_id", M_ID)` but still I am getting the same error! any other suggestion?

Comment: It looks like a good start (you can [edit] your question to show your new code), but you may also want to read [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Unfortunately, there is a lot of examples out there that use it, so not surprising that you found it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever what do you suggest then to solve my problem ?

Comment: Yes, those werent meant as solutions to the posted problem, just other things wrong in the code.  If you run the query on SQLSvr UI does it return what you expect?

Comment: @Plutonix yes it does return fine in SQL server

Comment: on which line do you get it?  executing the query or accessing the `item`?

Comment: @Plutonix I am getting it here: `cboISBNsave.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("book_name")`

Comment: Use the LOCALS and IMMEDIATE window to poke around in the datatable to see how many columns there are and what the names are.  Hard to be much help with this sort of Q because we dont have the DB or the Data (aside from obvious typos)

Comment: @Plutonix my English is not that good :( didn't get your last comment!

Comment: Try `cboISBNsave.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(0)`

Comment: ==debug it.  @DiscipleMichael has a good idea, try to get it by index.  the opther one would be `dt.Rows(0).Item(1)` ***if*** it returns 2 cols (hence the debug suggestion" find out what the return looks like - rows, cols, names, types)

Comment: Also looks like you're missing a space here `M_ID & "AND`

Comment: I did what Michael commented but still giving same error @Plutonix

Comment: One thing you should do is break the debugger right after you assign the query text, and check what query it is going to send.  Then, copy that query and past into SQL and run it.  See what it gives you.

Comment: sorry, but trying the get it by index **will not** cause the same error on *that* line.  you would not be asking for "book_name" but whatever the hell is in `item(0)`  @DiscipleMichael the OP changed the query to use params

Comment: @Plutonix no actually when I did like this it gave same error: `cboISBNsave.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(0)("book_name")` but when I wrote like this: `cboISBNsave.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(0)` then it brought nothing to `cboISBNsave` combobox but empty field yeah but this time there was no error!

Comment: @Hazmat set the query string in it's one line `Dim query as String = "......query here....."`  then set the set it in the on the next line `da = New SqlDataAdapter(query, cn)`  Set a breakline after the string set, and run the code... hover over the word query to see what it says it sends... then copy that and run on sql

Comment: @Hazmat your query is broken then

Comment: @DiscipleMichael but how is it possible when I am searching for single fields it returns value with no error but when I want to search both fields then it gives error?

Comment: not sure, but if you do what I said about the query string, you will know exactly what it's returning to your adapter

Comment: No reason to use params here, not that it's terrible to do so, but you need to keep it simple to figure out what is broken.  I strongly think there is something wrong with the query your code is sending SQL.  The best way to check it is what I listed above.

Comment: @DiscipleMichael solved it there wasn't any single problem from the start as I was insisting I just reordered filling the fields and now it works fine

Comment: @Plutonix solved it myself but still thanks for your help/time and also Michael's suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of headaches I just found out that I am only filling the fields in the wrong order, I selected `"book_name"` first in my SQL query but when I was filling the fields(comboboxes ->`cboIDSave` & `cboISBNsave`) I Was filling first ID field then book_name field although I must fill book_name field first and then ID field. So that's what I DID and now the code works fine :)

to summarize just change this:

```
 cboIDSave.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("member_id") 
 cboISBNsave.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("book_name")
```

to this:

```
cboISBNsave.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("book_name")
cboIDSave.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("member_id")
```